# Add CNAME record to Ubuntu to Verify Domain for Google

Tags: cname-record

I would like to add a cname record to my Ubuntu VPS to verify a domain for Google apps.

Just looking for the most simple commands to do this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're not providing any useful information to work with. Is your VPS a nameserver?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to VPS administration.  I purchased the vps and pointed the DNS settings from my domain registrar to the web host's nameservers.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: There's no simple "add cname command." These records are configured on nameservers. Many smaller shops or newer admins use other company's servers to provide those. You either have to use the configuration interfaces of their systems or establish your own nameserver and point the NS records there. That's more than a single question and should be handled by looking at howto guides.

Comment: "pointed the DNS settings from my domain registrar to the web host's nameservers."

Then you'll need to go into your web host's control panel and add the CNAME record like Google asks you to. Contact your web host's support if you are unable to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to go to the DNS settings control panel at your domain registrar and create the CNAME there. How to do this depends on the registrar but they'll probably have some documentation on how to do it on their site.